# Problem with curses.h library on M1 arm64 processor

Tags: c++, macos, clion

I am a macOS user with an M1 processor. For my project (without going into details) I decided to use the library:
curses.h
The problem is that I get an error message about "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64".
I would like to ask for help in solving the problem if possible. Im using CLion. C++ standard 20, MacOS 13.2.1.
Here is my code:

```
#include <curses.h> 
int main() {

    initscr();
    keypad( stdscr, TRUE );
    printw( "Character in bold:\n\n" );
    noecho(); // 2
    int letter = getch();
    printw( "The pressed char is:" );
    attron( A_BOLD );
    printw( "%d", letter );
    getch();
    endwin();

}
```

And my error:

```
FAILED: NameOfProject 
: && /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ -g -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.1.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/KeyBook.dir/main.cpp.o -o KeyBook   && :
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_endwin", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_initscr", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_keypad", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_noecho", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_printw", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_stdscr", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_wattr_on", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "_wgetch", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
```

I've tried to go online and reinstall ncurses, but it hasn't fixed anything. Using -lcurses doesn't work.

Comment: `curses.h` is not the "library". Its the header you include. You miss to link the library

Comment: "Using -lcurses doesn't work." why not? What happens when you try to link it?

Comment: My guess would be you've got an intel build of curses, you need to rebuild it for arm

Comment: Goodness me, someone still using `curses`. Last time I encountered this was about 1987.